# Preg match date field validation

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I try to "validate" a date field. I only want to allow, numeric chars and - character.

```
 $born_date=$_POST['date'];
 $goodchars = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","-");
 $char_re_good = '/['.preg_quote(join('', $goodchars), '/').']/';
       if (!(preg_match($char_re_good, $born_date))) {
            echo "not ok, contain INVALID chars"
       }else{
            echo "ok, contain valid chars"
       }
```

If i try to search for "1960" then OK. If i try to search for " asdfg" then NOT OK. 
But if i search for "1960/" then the output is OK. I dont understand why.

Could you help me modify to check if user only "0-9" and "-" chars fill out the field.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to "anchor" your expression, i.e. insert start of string ^ and end of string $ markers.

```
 preg_match('/^[0-9-]+$/', $born_date);
```

however, preg_match is not a way to validate dates. For example, the above will accept "99999999" etc

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but don´t you have to put the **-** at the start in a character class or escape it?

Comment: Stereofrog - works well. Thank you. Its not a real validate. I dont need it. I just wanna sure if valid characters filled..

Answer (score 5):

[user187291's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909954/preg-match-problem/1909969#1909969) will match date characters only, which is what you want. A quick way to validate a date is to try and convert it to a timestamp via [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime):

```
if (strtotime($date_str)!==false) {
  // The date is valid.
}
```

Comment: this is a simple search form. users can hit only 1960 without day and month. im not sure, but if i convert 1960 with strtotime, then i get false result.?! I will try.

Answer (score 0):

```
$char_re_good = "/^[0-9-]+$/";
```

Give that a try